# What does fetch() in meteor exactly does?

Tags: meteor, fetch

Experimenting with meteor I came across a behavior I did not expect of fetch. Let's say I have a function :

```
findStuff = function(){
  var cursor = Stuff.find({});
  console.log(stuff.fetch()); // just to check
  return cursor;
}
```

and I call it from a template

```
Template.stuff.helpers({
  stuff : function(){
    var stuff = findStuff();
    console.log(stuff.fetch());  // just to check
    return stuff; 
  }
});
```

The first log will correctly display the array but the second will display an empty array. I am quite confused about why it is so. My solution is to avoid calling fetch if I don't need it explicitly but I like to use it as a debugging tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read about [cursor.rewind()](http://docs.meteor.com/#rewind).

> The forEach, map, or fetch methods can only be called once on a
>   cursor. To access the data in a cursor more than once, use rewind to
>   reset the cursor.